# "send back" vs "feed back"

Tags: word-choice

According to the Cambridge dictionary send back means: "to return something to the place it came from" and according to the same dictionary "feed back means: "to put something back where it came from"

Comment: What's your problem? Note that the ***verb*** sense of "return to whence it came" (as in *Most of the company's annual profit is **fed back** into the business*) applies to the ***two-word*** form. That's not the same thing as the one-word noun ***feedback*** (as in *The company relies on **customer feedback** to guide future product development.*)

Answer (score 2):

“send” emphasizes the action of making something to go from one place to another place.

“feed” emphasizes the purpose of helping something grow.

Hence, “send back” emphasizes to return something; “feed back” emphasizes to return and help something grow.

For example:

I had to send the shirt back because it didn't fit me.

As profits are fed back into the trust, it sells shares to workers and reduces its own stake.

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/feed?q=Feed+